# Huawei Map Kit onCameraIdle method is not triggered

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to implement Huawei Map Kit
and using clustering feature. I called setOnCameraIdleListener right before setMarkersClustering and still onCameraIdle method is not triggers even though everything stays idle. What might be the problem?

Comment: Hi Binary Princess, can you please add you code? Makes it easier for us to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Map SDK, the OnCameraIdleListener listening callback code of the map is in the setMarkersClustering method.
Therefore, set MarkersClustering(true) and then setOnCameraIdleListener(this).
Like this:

```
map.setMarkersClustering(true);
map.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);
```

Currently, only this invoking sequence is supported.